# Как в gorm (golang) прописать связи таблиц?

Tags: postgresql, golang, orm

Есть 2 структуры

```
type Student struct {
    Id uint64 `sql:"AUTO_INCREMENT" gorm:"primary_key"`
    Name  string  `sql:"size:80`
}

type Struct1 struct { 
    Id uint64 `sql:"AUTO_INCREMENT" gorm:"primary_key"`
    StudentId  Student //`gorm:"ForeignKey:Id"`
    Time time.Time `sql:"DEFAULT:current_timestamp"`  
    Value int //Какие-нибудь значения
}
```

Я сделал миграцию и таблицы создались в БД

```
db.AutoMigrate(&Student{})
db.AutoMigrate(&Struct1{})
```

Но я хочу, что б в БД тоже создались связи с каскадным изменением.
То-есть сейчас я добавил студента id 1, а другая таблица никак не знает о существовании таблицы Students и в StudentId можно писать что хочешь.
Как через gorm прописать ключи?

Comment: В конвенции имён в `go` используется `ID` вместо `Id`. Но это, я так.

Comment: `StudentID` должен быть целым, а ссылка на структуру делается отдельно. Типа [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/z8JRSkpK)

Comment: При таком коде таблицы не связаны

Comment: Используйте `@"мой ник"`, комментируя не мои посты, что б я мог увидеть комментарий.

Comment: Ok.Спасибо @IvanBlack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например для таких моделей

```golang
// has_many Ys
type X struct {
    gorm.Model
}

// belongs_to X
type Y struct {
    gorm.Model
    XID uint
}
```

Во так

```
db.Model(&Y{}).AddForeignKey("x_id", "xes (id)", "CASCADE", "CASCADE")
```

Соответственно `RESTRICT` вместо `CASCADE` если надо. [Доки](http://jinzhu.me/gorm/database.html#migration). Первый `CASCADE` срабатывает `ON UPODATE` второй `ON DELETE`.

Итоговый SQL будет таким

```sql
ALTER TABLE "ys" -- к какой таблице добавляется ограничение
    ADD CONSTRAINT "ys_x_id_xes_id_foreign" -- имя ограничения
    FOREIGN KEY ("x_id") -- какая колонка будет внешним ключом (в таблице ys)
    REFERENCES xes (id) -- к какой таблице (к какой колонке)
    ON DELETE CASCADE   -- при удалении
    ON UPDATE CASCADE;  -- при обновлении
```

---

вероятно нужно будет обновить GORM с помощью

```
go get -u github.com/jinzhu/gorm
```

Comment: Я перепробовал что-то все варианты. Всёравно в базе ограничений нет. Можете пожалуйста написать пример? Я на оф сайте читал.

Comment: @RakzinRoman, всё работете. Вот [паста](http://pastebin.com/0YFmPVYg). Помни, что это ограничение не гарантирует, что Y будет обязательно относится к X. Для этого нужно добавить ещё `NOT NULL` к `x_id`.

Comment: @RakzinRoman, я имею ввиду, что `x_id` может остаться `NULL`-ом и ограничение не сработает в этом случае.

Comment: Ооо....как Ваш код целиком взял- всё работает, а сам частями брал по чуть-чуть везде....Благодарю

Comment: @"Ivan Black" @Ivan Black Пишет отношение "xes" не существует . Я не понял, а что такое здесь вообще xes? db.Model(&Y{}).AddForeignKey("x_id", "xes (id)", "CASCADE", "CASCADE")   - здесь мы второй таблице(Y) поле x_id  привязываем к полю X(id) -тоесть к таблице X полю id. Я правильно понял? нужно именно со скобками? На оф сайте написано, но у меня не работает- что-то не то делаю...

Comment: @RakzinRoman, принято записывать имена таблиц во множественном числе. И `X` превращается в `xes`. Типа: иксы. И `gorm` при миграции, по-умолчанию, будет делать это в автоматическом режиме. Собственно, если таблицы `xes` нету, значит её нужно мигрировать. Посмотри в пасте, что выше. Там сначала миграция обоих таблиц, а потом только добавление этого ограничения.

Comment: @"Ivan Black" разобрался, спасибо.